# Read uint8array directly from uWebsockets server

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

I am trying use the uWebSockets library to read binary ArrayBuffer data sent from a web client.

I found a question on the repo issues that describes this for the case of text/blob data, but I want to parse uint8array data coming in from the web client:

- https://gist.github.com/WesThorburn/581d8b7a0ed70bc386b8c388336ad318
- https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/issues/508

I am using the very simple example client:

```
int main()
{
    uWS::Hub h;

    h.onMessage([](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws, char *message, size_t length, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
        uint8_t messageString [length]; //Create char array with length of message length
        cout << "length: " << length << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { //Iterate through each character in the message
          messageString[i] = (uint8_t)message[i];   //Add message character to messageString
        }
        cout << "Message: " << &messageString[1] << endl;

        ws->send (message, length, opCode);
    });

    h.listen (3000);
    h.run();
}
```

and on the client side I do:

```
 {
     ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
     ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
     ws.onopen     = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
     ws.onclose    = function (evt) { onClose(evt) };
     ws.onmessage  = function (evt) { onMessage(evt) };
     ws.onerror    = function (evt) { onError(evt) };
 }
```

and send a `uint8array` down the socket.  The text/blob example does not work, trying to read it as a `uint8_t` array does not work, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to read this so that the data is usable.  Note that the echo back to the client does however work - I get back what I put in.

Answer (score 0):

Reading data from clients and responding to them is as simple as:

```
h.onMessage([](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws, char *message, size_t, length, uWS::OpCode opCode) {
    std::string receivedMessage(message, length);
    ws->send("Reponse from server", uWS::OpCode::BINARY);
});
```